# Is there a way to convert vector<bool> to int in constant time?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

Currently, I am using the **accumulator** function to convert a vector to int. But it takes the time of distance between first to last parameters. Is there a constant time implementation of this?

Comment: If you're using `vector<bool>` as a bitset I recommend you switch to `boost::dynamic_bitset` instead.  It's built for this.

Comment: Check out `std::bitset`. It has a [to_ulong() function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) for converting the contents to an unsigned integer.

Comment: I do not want to use bitset as it has fixed bitset, neither into boost dynamic bitset

Comment: `int` has an upper limit so the vector has to have an upper limit in size.  Therefore, calling accumulate on it is constant.